# When should I access properties with self in swift?

Tags: swift

In a simple example like this, I can omit self for referencing backgroundLayer because it's unambiguous which backgroundLayer the backgroundColor is set on.

```
class SpecialView: UIView {
    let backgroundLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    init() {
        backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    }
}
```

But, just like in Objective-C, we can confuse things by adding local variables (or constants) named similarly. Now the backgroundColor is being set on the non-shape layer:

```
class SpecialView: UIView {
    let backgroundLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    init() {
        var backgroundLayer = CALayer()

        backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    }
}
```

(this is resolved by using self.backgroundLayer.backgroundColor)

In Objective-C I always eschewed ivars for properties and properties were always prefixed with self for clarity. I don't have to worry about ivars in swift but are there other considerations for when I should use self in swift?

Comment: Consider accepting a solution.

Answer (score 93):

The only times `self` is required are when referencing a property inside a closure and, as you pointed out, to differentiate it from a local variable with the same name.

However, personally, I prefer to always write "self" because:

1. That is an instant and obvious sign that the variable is a property. This is important because it being a property means that its state can vary more widely and in different ways than a local variable. Also, changing a property has larger implications than changing a local variable.
2. The code does not need to be updated if you decide to introduce a parameter or variable with the same name as the property
3. Code can be easily copied in and out of closures that do require self

Comment: Yes and yes. Sometimes brevity and clarity are at odds - always use `self` and you won't get stung by a rare case of overlap.

Comment: @NateCook I actually filed a bug with Apple about making self required and I encourage you to do the same if you agree :)

Comment: The reason I like *not* using self is that when closure capture forces you to use self, it then stands out (which is good, because referencing self in a closure retains it, unlike other contexts, so you want it to look "different")

Comment: @Catfish_Man that is a good point. I forgot self is required in closures

Comment: I reckon not using `self` keeps the code concise and clear. This is especially true when you are writing out formulas using the properties. And thanks to Xcode 7's syntax colouring it's very clear which variables are local and which ones are properties.

Comment: I agree on all points. To a degree this comes down to personal design taste, but clarity is better than brevity most of the time.

Comment: @Nikolozi Xcode's coloring gets lost when you're doing, for instance, a pull request review. In that case having `self.` does add extra clarity.

Comment: @Gobe that's a shortcoming of the PR review tool. You shouldn't add clutter to your code just to improve your PR review experience.

Comment: @Nikolozi I'd overall agree, but the 5 characters from `self.` are definitely worth the added clarity IMHO :)

Comment: I always write `self`. makes my intention more clear to other readers.

Comment: 2 and 3 are the exact reasons I dropped using `self`. If your code relies on some vague practice, such as "variable names can be the same as properties because they can be told apart through `self`", but someone forgets to use `self`, that's a great place for bugs right there. Others have mentioned capturing `self` in closures.  And I personally feel like `self` is just a relic of the ObjC era when you had no other way of calling a method.

Comment: Is there a performance difference between using ‘self.property’ and just ‘property’? In ObjC, for instance, accessing the ivar directly (without self.) was faster.

Comment: When you are reviewing other people code, it is much more clearer when they use self for properties. Not all diff editors have this color syntax mentioned.

Answer (score 20):

Most of the time we can skip `self.` when we access class properties.

1. However there is one time when we **MUST** use it: when we try to set `self.property` in a closure:

   ```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
       // we cannot assign to properties of self
       self.view = nil 

       // but can access properties
       someFunc(view)
   })
   ```
2. one time when we **SHOULD** use it: so you don't mess a local variable with class property:

   ```
   class MyClass {
       var someVar: String = "class prop"

       func setProperty(someVar:String = "method attribute") -> () {
           print(self.someVar) // Output: class property
           print(someVar) // Output: method attribute
       }
   }
   ```
3. other places where we **CAN** use `self.` 
   before property just to be expressive about were variable/constant comes from.

Answer (score 11):

Looking at [Ray Wenderlich's style guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#use-of-self)

> **Use of Self**
>
> For conciseness, avoid using self since Swift does not require it to access an object's properties or invoke its methods.
>
> Use self only when required by the compiler (in @escaping closures, or in initializers to disambiguate properties from arguments). In other words, if it compiles without self then omit it.

[Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html) makes the same recommendation.

> **The self Property**
>
> Every instance of a type has an implicit property called self, which is exactly equivalent to the instance itself. You use the self property to refer to the current instance within its own instance methods.
>
> The `increment()` method in the example above could have been written like this:

```
func increment() {
    self.count += 1
}
```

> **In practice, you don’t need to write self in your code very often.** If you don’t explicitly write self, Swift assumes that you are referring to a property or method of the current instance whenever you use a known property or method name within a method. This assumption is demonstrated by the use of count (rather than self.count) inside the three instance methods for Counter.
>
> **The main exception to this rule occurs when a parameter name for an instance method has the same name as a property of that instance.** In this situation, the parameter name takes precedence, and it becomes necessary to refer to the property in a more qualified way. You use the self property to distinguish between the parameter name and the property name.
>
> Here, self disambiguates between a method parameter called x and an instance property that is also called x:

```
struct Point {
    var x = 0.0, y = 0.0

    func isToTheRightOf(x: Double) -> Bool {
        return self.x > x
    }
}

let somePoint = Point(x: 4.0, y: 5.0)
if somePoint.isToTheRightOf(x: 1.0) {
    print("This point is to the right of the line where x == 1.0")
}

// Prints "This point is to the right of the line where x == 1.0"
```

Comment: Can you cite the relevant part of Apple's documentation? I cannot find a recommendation.

Comment: @Apfelsaft I've updated my answer. The relevant recommendation is under the section The Self Property. Swift documentation states "In practice, you don’t need to write self in your code very often."

Comment: It's not a recommendation, It just an explanation about the self reference with a big BUT detailing some particular cases where you must use self. 
Do not translate a personal interpretation to a recommendation.
I prefer to use it only in one way (Always use self) and not to have ambiguity on my code, but again: It's my preference.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to go against the flow and not use `self` unless absolutely required.

The reason why is that two of the main reasons to use `self` is

- When capturing `self` in a block
- When setting `self` as a delegate

In both cases, `self` will be captured as a `strong` reference. This might be what you want, but in many cases, you actually want to use a `weak` one.

Therefor, forcing the developer to use `self` as an exception and not a rule will make this `strong` capture more conscious, and let him reflect on this decision.

Answer (score 3):

As Apple documentation says in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html

> **The self Property**
>
> Every instance of a type has an implicit property called self, which
>   is exactly equivalent to the instance itself. You use the self
>   property to refer to the current instance within its own instance
>   methods.
>
> The increment() method in the example above could have been written
>   like this:
>
> ```
> func increment() {
>     self.count += 1
> }
> ```
>
> In practice, you don’t need to write self in your code very often. If
>   you don’t explicitly write self, Swift assumes that you are referring
>   to a property or method of the current instance whenever you use a
>   known property or method name within a method. This assumption is
>   demonstrated by the use of count (rather than self.count) inside the
>   three instance methods for Counter.
>
> The main **exception** to this rule occurs when a parameter name for an
>   instance method has the same name as a property of that instance. In
>   this situation, the parameter name takes precedence, and it becomes
>   necessary to refer to the property in a more qualified way. You use
>   the self property to distinguish between the parameter name and the
>   property name.
>
> Here, self disambiguates between a method parameter called x and an
>   instance property that is also called x:
>
> ```
> struct Point {
>     var x = 0.0, y = 0.0
>     func isToTheRightOf(x: Double) -> Bool {
>         return self.x > x
>     }
> }
> let somePoint = Point(x: 4.0, y: 5.0)
> if somePoint.isToTheRightOf(x: 1.0) {
>     print("This point is to the right of the line where x == 1.0")
> }
> // Prints "This point is to the right of the line where x == 1.0"
> ```
>
> Without the self prefix, Swift would assume that both uses of x
>   referred to the method parameter called x.

I would prefer to keep using self whenever I'm using a property to omit these misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

As Nick said, in objective-c we had ivars + synthesized properties which gave the _internal variable names to delineate things. Eg.

```
@IBOutlet (nonatomic,strong) UITableView *myTableView;
```

resulting in  `_myTableView` to be (preferably) referenced internally - and `self.myTableView` to be reference beyond the class. While this is pretty black and white, consider the exception when programmatically instantiating views, you can gain clarity/ simplicity / reduce boilerplate by removing self.

```
@interface CustomVC:UIViewController
{
     UITableView *myTableView; 
}
```

In swift, the public / internal properties clarify this scope. 
If it's a public property that other classes will interact with err on self.
Otherwise if it's internal skip self and avoid the automatic repetition.
The compiler will catch you when it's needed.

```
// UIViewcontroller swift header
public var title: String? // Localized title for use by a parent controller.
public var navigationItem: UINavigationItem { get } 

/// In your class
self.title  = "Clarity"
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()

// In superclass  
 @property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *screenName  // use self.screenName in swift subclass

@IBOutlet myTableView:UITableView  // use self
public var myTableView:UITableView  // use self

internal var myTableView:UITableView // skip self
var myTableView:UITableView // skip self
```