# Which do you use 'obj' or 'self.obj'?

Tags: swift, function, object

I have a trivial question.

Which do you use A or B in this case? Why?
obj and self.obj are exactly the same.

```
let obj = MyClass()

func sampleFunction(obj: MyClass) {
    // A
    obj.xxx()

    // B
    self.obj.xxxx()
}
```

Comment: I think that generally speaking 'self.obj' is better for the understanding of who exactly that variable belongs to.

Comment: Your statement that "obj and self.obj are exactly the same" is not true... They are NOT the same, since `obj` is the parameter of the function and not the instance variable.

Comment: Compare [When should I access properties with self in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215578/when-should-i-access-properties-with-self-in-swift).

Comment: Quite simply `obj`, and `self.obj` or just `x` and `self.x` are not always exactly the same they shouldn't be treated as such. An understanding of scope is required.

Comment: Thank you for a lot of advice.

Yeah, "obj and self.obj are exactly the same" was incorrect.
My question is the same as the post @Martin R mentioned and it has been clear.
Thenk you, everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self.obj` refers to the instance of the class you are in and access the obj **instance variable** defined. Referring to `obj` will refer to the named parameter within the **scope of the function**.

```
class Test {

let obj = "Global"

    func sampleFunction(obj: String) {
        // A
        print(obj)

        // B
        print(self.obj)
    }
}

var t = Test()

t.sampleFunction("Internal")
```

Paste this into a Playground for a demo of this to aid the explanation.

It is subjective whether or not to use `self` to refer to instance variables, but if there is another local variable or named parameter with the same name as the instance variable in that scope - you **must** use `self` to differentiate like in the example.

It is a good rule-of-thumb to always use `self` to refer to instance variables, this improves readability and decreases the chance of bugs relating to conflicting local variable names in scope occurring.

Comment: I fall in the camp that *omits* `self` whenever you can. Cases like OP's are ones where that doesn't work.

Comment: Personally I usually use `self`, but I want to point out: If `self` is needed to increase the readability and/or avoid conflicts with local variables, the underlying issue is not not using `self`, but having a scope that grew too big — the function body, the closure has too many lines of code and/or if-else branches.

Comment: By increase readability I mean that at a glance I can instantly see that a variable is an instance variable.

Comment: Sure, and I say, if that really increases the readability, the scope grew too big.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I'm understanding the scope.
And I asked which object do you use when obj and self.obj refer the same object.
I think "this improves readability and decreases the chance of bugs..." is the best answer for me, thank you very much.