# Swift: Should I Use `self` in ViewController Methods in Swift/iOS?

Tags: swift

There are two way to call variables & methods in ViewController:

**Case 1: Using `self`**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var count = 0;
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.count = 1
        self.myFunc()
    }

    func myFunc(){
       ...
    }
}
```

**Case 2: Access directly**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var count = 0;
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        count = 1
        myFunc()
    }
    func myFunc(){
       ...
    }
}
```

Should I call variables and methods with the instance `self` in the scalable project at everywhere, or access them directly, as calling with the instance is a good way?

There is any difference between those two a function-calls in a class:

```
self.myFunc()
```

VS

```
myFunc()
```

It is working in both ways. It make any difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I access properties with self in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215578/when-should-i-access-properties-with-self-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice would be that we should avoid unnecessary calls with ***self***.

- It should be used when it's necessary like you want have a initialiser or a function with same name as your variable then you can use ***self*** to distinguish between both.
- Another place would be the clousure.